# change the distance between lines in align environment

Tags: spacing

Is there any way to change the spacing between lines in the align/align* environment ? I tried to put `\vspace{.2cm}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `\vspace` adds a space, to remove it, you must specify a negative value. `\vspace{-.2cm}`

Comment: do you mean change the spacing globally or change the space in one place use `\\[3cm]` to change the space after a specific line